# How to display the true position of a free fall object in javascript

Tags: javascript, physics, p5.js

I want to make a physics simulation where I have a circle on a screen and then make it fall with the acceleration of gravity 9.8m/s/s (or 37039pixels/s/s). I created one with p5js but  I am unsure if my math is correct.

```
var bounce;
var start;
var x;
var velocity;
var acceleration;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, windowHeight);
  
  //1
  bounce = 0;
  x = 25;
  velocity = 0;
  acceleration = 9.8;
  
  start = false;
}

function draw() {
  //derawing
  background(0);
  circle(width/2, x, 50);
  if (keyIsPressed) {
      start = true;
  }
  if (start) {
    
    //2
    velocity = velocity + acceleration/deltaTime;
    x = x + velocity/deltaTime*3780;
    
    //collison
    if (x + 25 + velocity > height) {
      x = height - 25;
      velocity = velocity*-1*bounce;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you check your math if you were doing the math by hand?

Comment: Where do you define deltaTime?

Comment: @phatfingers I'm using p5.js so its predefined

Comment: @MohammadKherfan the variable "bounce" and the multiplication of 3780 seem to be unnecessary

Comment: Your calculation for velocity is wrong.  `v = v0 + a * t`